# GDAL doesn't work on Geoserver for ECW (and CentOS)

Tags: geoserver, gdal, ecw

in a server with centos 7, tomcat8, java 1.8.0_121, geoserver v.2.10.1, i followed this link  to install the gdal plugin:http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html

i can see the list of the stores including the ecw store. but when i try to select the store geoserver crashes and restart.

I've tryed the gdalinfo command to check the file. With all the files i tested i have the same error:

**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
gdalinfo.sh: line 5: 19137 Aborted                 (core dumped) java -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" gdalinfo $input**

i've searched in everywhere and it seems to me that this is a bug in the gdal plugin.

Is it possible to view an ECW file in a GeoServer installed on a centos server?

Comment: can you view the ecw file with your gdal install?

Comment: how i could do it? i have only geoserver installed on the server.

Comment: `$ gdalinfo --formats | sort` can you see ecw driver in the list? It is very possible that your gdal was build w/out ecw support (ecw is a proprietary driver after all - consume .tiff if possible)

Comment: No. In effect, i can't see any ECW driver in the list. How could i add it?

Comment: You need to compile GDAL with ecw support, since there are only few and outdated Linux packages available that include ecw. https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW and https://www.surfaces.co.il/gdal-and-ecw-on-centos-5/ might lead you towards your aim.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the tips of Andrej, iant e nickves (thank you guys) and i've tryed to install GDAL with ecw support.
if check the list of the driver with the command:

```
$ gdalinfo --formats | sort
```

i can't find the ECW driver, but now, if i use the gdalinfo.sh command in the gdal192\javainfo folder i don't see the error anymore and i receive the following answer:

```
# sh gdalinfo.sh /root/Downloads/3741011.ecw
```

**Driver: ECW/ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
Files: /root/Downloads/3741011.ecw
Size is 12194, 9992
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (290747.225122,4641666.725122)
Pixel Size = (0.15,-0.15)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (290747.225122,4641666.725122)
Lower Left  (290747.225122,4640167.925122)
Upper Right (292576.32512199995,4641666.725122)
Lower Right (292576.32512199995,4640167.925122)
Center      (291661.77512199996,4640917.325122)
Band 1 Block=12194x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 6097x4996, 3048x2498, 1524x1249, 762x624, 381x312, 190x156
Band 2 Block=12194x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 6097x4996, 3048x2498, 1524x1249, 762x624, 381x312, 190x156
Band 3 Block=12194x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 6097x4996, 3048x2498, 1524x1249, 762x624, 381x312, 190x156**

that seems ok.
now, when i try with geoserver it still crashes.

Maybe i have to point the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable path to some other folder?

Thank you for your help.

**--> UPDATE: restarted tomcat and everything is working fine! Thank you all**

Comment: Is there any step by step documents which you had followed?

Comment: no. i couldn't find any documentation that explains step by step what is needed to do in order to make the ecw working with geoserver...